# 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 = 2016

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Add the four basic operators $\times\div+\,\;-$ and optionally brackets to:

$10 \quad 9 \quad 8 \quad 7 \quad 6 \quad 5 \quad 4 \quad 3 \quad 2 \quad 1$

To get the total $2016$.

Rules:

- We are looking for the simplest solution - i.e. the least amount of characters (ignoring spaces). Please include your character count in your answer.
- Keep the order; do not add or combine numbers.
- Use all four operators at least once.

Credit for initial concept: Alex Bellos

Comment: Is it one of each operator? And can you combine numbers (eg. 2 and 1 makes 21)?

Comment: If there are multiple ways of doing this, do you want the most complex, the most simple, or some other criteria?

Comment: Do the numbers need to be in that order in the equation?

Comment: Fun fact, if Carat was allowed: `10 x 9 + 8 + 7 * 6 + 5 ^ 4 x 3 + 2 -1` (credit: @TheDanWoods Twitter)

Comment: It's possible only if there's a zero available. Otherwise, you can get 2013, 2014, 2015, 2017, 2018 and 2019, or 1008 and 4032. No 2016.

Comment: 20160 is also possible.

Comment: @rybo111 there are actually 2 ways with a single carat: 
`10 x 9 + 8 + 7 x 6 + 5 ^ 4 x 3 + 2 - 1`
`10 x 9 + 8 x 7 - 6 + 5 ^ 4 x 3 + 2 - 1`

edit: oops 2 not 5 - foiled by integer division!

Comment: So, if this gets polished and nailed down (looks like most of that is already done), are we going to make it an annual puzzle?

Comment: @Iszi I'm happy for the community to fine-tune the challenge for the years ahead as it wasn't my idea to begin with. But perhaps each year could have different limitations to keep it fresh.

Comment: Is it possible to have an average computer find the optimal solution in reasonable time?

Comment: @Evorlor There's no solution. I've checked it with javascript.

Comment: Is it kosher to edit a puzzle around here after someone answers it?

Comment: @Yakk sounds like a question for Meta. What edit are you referring to?

Comment: @rybo111 http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/25041/11838 answer predated your first edit, and you edited your puzzle then told that person to change their answer.  There may be other answers that predate the puzzle rule change.

Comment: @Yakk When the question was first posted, there were a number of questions which needed clarification. It wouldn't have been kosher to leave the question as it was.

Answer (score 24):

**22 characters**

> $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \div 5 \div (4 - 3 + 2) \times 1$

I looked at @Will's answer and found a way to improve on it.

Comment: Ah, that's nice one - good job!

Comment: This is great! Is it possible without brackets?

Comment: @rybo111 - Brute force turns up no solutions without groupings using only +, -, *, and /. Closest two are: `10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3-2+1 = 2015.0` and `10*9*8*7/6/5*4*3+2-1 = 2017.0`. This should be accepted. :)

Comment: @Will keep that second one saved for next year!

Comment: Couldn't this save one character? Seems to me the final operator is unnecessary.

Comment: @Jordan how do you mean?

Comment: @rybo111 brackets are an implicit multiplication. The answer is exactly the same if the final `*` is removed, but with one less character.

Comment: @Jordan Sorry, can you explain what you mean by removing the final `*`? That would leave `...2) 1`.

Comment: @rybo111 Yes, that is the implicit multiplication Jordan is referring to.

Comment: @hexafraction I thought so, but it doesn't work on Google so assumed I was doing something wrong

Comment: @rybo111 There is plenty of different mathematical notation that is accepted by mathematical professionals that doesn't work on Google, for various reasons (ranging from the fact that it can't be written as plain text, to that Google simply doesn't implement it).

Answer (score 18):

**22 characters**

I don't think you can beat Joel's answer at 22 characters, but there are some nice ways to tie it (including a variation of Joel's for completeness):

> $(10 - 9 + 8 \times 7 \times 6 - 5 + 4) \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$
>  $10 - 9 + 8 \times 7 \times (6 \times 5 + 4 \times 3 \div 2) - 1$
>  $10 - 9 + 8 \times 7 \times (6 + 5 \times 4 \times 3 \div 2) - 1$
>  $10 - 9 + 8 \times 7 \times 6 \div (5 - 4) \times 3 \times 2 - 1$
>  $10 - 9 + 8 \times 7 \times 6 \times (5 + 4) \div 3 \times 2 - 1$
>  $10 - 9 + 8 \times 7 \times 6 \times (5 + 4 + 3) \div 2 - 1$
>  $10 + (9 \times 8 \times 7 - 6 + 5) \times 4 - 3 \times 2 \div 1$
>  $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \div (6 - 5 + 4 - 3 \div 2 - 1)$
>  $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \div (6 \times 5 \div 4 - 3 \times 2 + 1)$
>  $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \div (5 \times 4 - 3 \times 2 + 1)$
>  $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \div (5 + 4 \times 3 - 2 \times 1)$
>  $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \div 5 \div (4 - 3 + 2) \times 1$

There are other ways but many of them are trivial (change $\div 1$ to $\times 1$ or vice-versa, or $\div 1)$ to $)\div 1$

If we didn't have the restriction that we need to use all the different operators there is also a very nice solution:

> $ 10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \div (5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1)$

Comment: The non-restriction version is so clean!

Comment: @rybo111 Yeah, I like how the `/` is right in the middle.

Comment: You found so many ways. Is there any generalized method to come with these? or just random guesses?

Comment: 22 characters is indeed the best possible solution as it cannot be done without parentheses (verified by exhaustive search)

Comment: I don't understand why nobody is taking the hints in multiple comments.  You can take many of these to 21 characters by simply removing any multiplication operators next to a parentheses.

Comment: @Mahesha999 You can generate every expression in postfix notation without needing parenthesis. I just generated a bunch of valid postfix expressions with the numerals in decreasing order and then checked if they evaluated to 2016 and if they did I converted them to infix. I don't think I did an exhaustive search though.

Answer (score 12):

I came up with:

> $(10 - 9) \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \times (5 - 4 + 3 + 2 \div 1)$

This is **9 operators** and **2 required groupings**, for a total of **24 characters**.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: All right, editing in division real quick

Comment: Great stuff! Can anyone beat 24 characters?

Comment: I was just writing an answer with your edit.

Comment: You could also remove the two asterisks right next to the parentheses i.e. 6(5-4) = 6*(5-4)

Comment: @rybo is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

> $10 + 9 \times 8 - 7 + 654  \times 3 - 21$

**17 Characters**...  Is mushing numbers together allowed?  Also, yay Mathematica.

Comment: Oh, wait, it isn't allowed.

Comment: Still another cool solution though!

Comment: Also missing $ ÷ $

Comment: I like your solution and your use of the word mushing!  How do you find something like this using Mathematica?  Is there a special command you used?

Answer (score 6):

If we allow for implicit multiplication of parenthesized expressions then the following solutions, all of **length 20**, become possible

> $10\times 9\times 8\times 7(6\div 5-4+3) 2\times 1$
>  $10\times 9\times 8\times 7 (6\div 5-4+3) 2\div 1$
>  $10\times 9\times 8 (7-6\div 5-4+3-2) 1$

This list has been generated via exhaustive search, and excludes needlessly parenthesizing expressions that only contain multiplication or division.

Comment: Bravo! 21 was the previous leader with implicit multiplication

Answer (score 3):

**21 chars**

> $10 \times 9 \times 8 (7 - 6 \div 5 - 4 + 3 - 2 \times 1)$

Comment: My bad - but still you are missing one operator.

Comment: @assylias It's not necessary, it's inferred. https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110427155042AACb7d8

Answer (score 1):

**22 Chars:**

> 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6/(5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1)

Comment: @PaulPro already posted this solution

Answer (score 1):

**24 chars**:

> $(10-9+8) \times 7 \times (6 \times 5 + 4-3 + 2-1)$
>
>  $9 \times 7 \times 32 = 2016$

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more with **22 characters** not mentioned in @PaulPro's answer:

> 10*9*8*7*6/(5*4-3-2*1)

Edit: As @DanHenderson pointed out, this has no + operator.

Comment: Has no + operator.

Answer (score 1):

**22 chars**

```
±10*9*8*7*6/(5+4+3+2+1)
```

If ± is valid as usage of - character, then you get two answers, which of one is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

**<s>22</s> 20 characters**

> 10 + 9 * 8 * 7 * 4 - 6 / 3 - 5 - 2 - 1

Without order :(

Comment: I count 20 characters.

Comment: You have changed the order of the numbers so this answer is invalid but otherwise well done

Answer (score 0):

**21!**

> 10*9*8*7*6/(5+4+3+2+1)

But not valid, I guess...

Comment: This was already included in @PaulPro’s answer, and a couple of others’.

Answer (score 0):

**27 characters** (missing `/`):

> (10-9)(8*7)(6-5)(4)(3)(2+1)

and **22 characters** (missing `-`):

> 10*9*8*7*6/(5+4+3+2+1)

Comment: Missing minus in last suggestion, and missing / in first