# 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 = 2017

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Add the four basic operators $\times\div+\,\;-$ and optionally brackets to:

$10 \quad 9 \quad 8 \quad 7 \quad 6 \quad 5 \quad 4 \quad 3 \quad 2 \quad 1$

To get the total $2017$.

Rules:

- Look for the simplest solution - i.e. the least amount of characters (ignoring spaces). Please include your character count in your answer.
- Keep the order; do not add or combine numbers.
- Use all four operators at least once.

Credit for initial concept: Alex Bellos

---

<sub>Previous year: [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25039/10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-2016).</sub>

Comment: Is implicit multiplication allowed?

Comment: For best solution you can mix up the numbers like `109X87+6543-21`

Comment: As of 2017 [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) is invading puzzling.

Comment: Just being curious about it: is there a known algorithm to solve it? (given inputs: list of possible numbers, desired result). I'm thinking about dynamic programing. Also don't know how I could call this problem to look for litterature.

Comment: @pltrdy Have you read [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15021/1871)?

Comment: @xzczd ty. It actually looks not straightforward :p Thats what i asked ty

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This one is 20 characters:

> $10×9×8×7 \div 6 \div 5×4×3 + 2 - 1$

Comment: @Paparazzi thanks - I think I left my counting skills in 2016.

Comment: Will work for the next two years as well (changing the final - to a x or +)

Comment: @TomCarpenter And it would also work for 2013-2015 by flipping the sign for 2 and manipulating the operator for 1 accordingly. This should also be the shortest answer, considering it has no brackets.

Comment: I wrote a script to try all combinations without parenthesis, this is the only one it finds.

Comment: @TomCarpenter no it would not: a `-` sign would be missing.

Comment: @Cœur fair point, missed that. Would work for 13-15 as Reti43 said.

Comment: You used all the integers, and this is the smallest number of characters of course (since it has no parenthesis). You get the tick!

Answer (score 15):

One can even find $2017$ by using only 5 numbers given in the question without changing the order as below:

> $9×8×7×4+1=2017$

Here are the actual answers for the question:

1. > $(10+9×8×7-6-5)×4+3+2×1=2017$ - **22 Chars**
2. > $(10×9×8×7)\div((6×5)\div(4×3))+2-1=2017$ - **28 Chars**
3. > $10×9×8×7×6\div5\div(4-3+2)+1=2017$ - **22 Chars**
4. > $(10+9×8×7-6-5)×4+3+2\div1=2017$ - **22 Chars**
5. > $10×9×8×7\div(6+5+4)×3×2+1=2017$ - **22 Chars**
6. > $10-9+8×7×6×(5-4)×3×2\div1=2017$ - **22 Chars**
7. > $(10-9+8)×7×(6-5+(4-3)×2)+1=2017$ - **26 Chars**
8. > $(10+9)×8×(7+6)+5+4×3×(2+1)=2017$ - **26 Chars**

Comment: You can simplify some of those, considering `a ÷ (b ÷ c) = a ÷ b × c` and `a ÷ (b × c) = a ÷ b ÷ c`

Comment: #3 has mismatching brackets

Comment: Can you include the number of characters for each?

Comment: @IAmInPLS fixed all errors...

Answer (score 2):

**22 characters**:

> $10×9×8×7×6÷5÷(4−3+2)+1$

There may be less, but pretty happy about this

There is also:

> $10×9×8×7×6÷(5+4×3−2)+1$

Which is same length but slightly different

Answer (score 1):

> (((10*9*8*7)/(6*5))*4*3)+2-1=2017

Answer (score 1):

> 2017 = 10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1+987+654+321

Comment: While this is a rather interesting result, this is not an answer to the question.